Mutiple package Name in React-Native Project
I have created a React Native application. Now, I need to create multiple applications using the same codebase but with different app names, app icons, and I also need to publish them on the Play Store.
To achieve this, I need each application to have a different package name so that I can create separate .aab bundles for each application. I have tried to create different .env files for each application, but I'm unsure how to correctly use them in the build.gradle file.
Could you please help me with this?

Please check this out https://medium.com/@svbala99/react-native-set-up-environment-flavours-dev-staging-prod-using-react-native-config-update-c09b0081e424

You can try using the react-native-config
defaultConfig {
    applicationId project.env.get("APP_ID")
}

https://github.com/lugg/react-native-config?tab=readme-ov-file#android

Then i don't need to change the package name in the manifest and mainactivity file?

You should use it in Manifest files
